# how to set rails gem 'rich' upload file size?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

this gem from https://github.com/bastiaanterhorst/rich

I setup with rails_admin,but upload file size is 15mb(default).
where can i resize it up to 100mb ?

please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not easy. Rich hardcodes the validates_attachment_size 15Mb value in rich_file.rb. If you wanted to make the limit smaller, you could add a more restrictive validation like this:

**application.rb**

```
config.after_initialize do
  Rich::RichFile.validates_attachment_size(:rich_file, :less_than=>3.megabyte, :message => "must be smaller than 3MB")
end
```

However, since you want to make the upload size less restrictive, a non-ideal but workable solution is to copy the rich_file.rb model into your rails directory at apps/models/rich/rich_file.rb directory and change the code directly:

**rich_file.rb**

```
validates_attachment_size :rich_file, :less_than=>100.megabyte, :message => "must be smaller than 100MB"
```

Answer (score 1):

Setting it to 100MB is probably a bad idea because the server will most likely timeout after 1 minute or so, unless you push it to a background job, or have some way to keep the current connection alive.